# Bootstrap nav hover color is too narrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav, col

I"m creating a [bootstrap project](http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/). A team member created the nav bar with icons, but this is our first time using Bootstrap.

While everything is mostly working, we are having an issue with the text not centering under the icon, and when you hover over it the text on Contact Us and Contribute hang out of the "box"

Media Queries are being used to re-size the icon, but even when I stripped out the media query styles the text hangs out of the "box"

Any suggestions for how to fix this error?

[Screenshot of Hover issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEoF9.png)

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Kent Food Bank & Emergency Services</title>



<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/readable_css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/readable_css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<div class="container head">
  <!---Top of the page-->

<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" >
            <img id="logo" class="img-responsive"  alt="This is the logo" src="http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/images/logo-transparent.png" >
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 navbar center-block" >
      <!--Centers Nav On Headers-->

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">Menu<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center ">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="index.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-home fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Home</span>
                    </a></p>
                </li>
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="contribute.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-users fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Contribute
                    </a></p>
                </li>
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="gethelp.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-cutlery fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Get&nbsp;Help
                    </a></p>
                </li>
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="calendar.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-calendar fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Calendar
                    </a></p>
                </li>
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="location.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Location</a></p>
                    </li>
              <li class="nav  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 text-center">
                    <p><a class="text-center col-xs-12 nav-fonts" href="contactus.php">
                            <span class="text-center icon-in-nav fa fa-phone-square fa-3x"></span>
                            <br />Contact&nbsp;Us
                    </a></p>
                </li>
          </ul>

      </div>
</div>


<div class="hidden-xs col-sm-2 col-md-1 ">


    <!--Paypal Donate Button-->
    <div style="width: auto">
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (Links to an external site.)" method="post" target="_top">

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HPNP9YXHUXN4G">
        <input type="image"   class="img-responsive" src="http://teambinary.greenrivertech.net/images/paypaldonate.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
         <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12"><hr class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="motto" class="pull-right"><p>Serving low-income residents of the Kent School District</p></div>

</div>
 </div>
   <script>
  //This javascript manipulates the logo size.
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var windowWidth = $(document).width();
      var imageSize = windowWidth/4;

      if(windowWidth > 767){
        $("#logo").css("width", imageSize + "px");
    }else{
        $("#logo").css("width", "100%");
    }

    });

      $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowWidth = $(document).width();
        var imageSize = windowWidth/4;

        if(windowWidth > 767){
          $("#logo").css("width", imageSize + "px");
      }else{
          $("#logo").css("width", "100%");
      }

    });


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to
1) Expand what you make each section (col-md-3 -> 4)

2) You can also try to use this: (.col-md-offset-3)

Those are the only ones that I came across.